# ios two ways custom delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, delegates

I have two classes `A` and `B`. I had one delete to pass a variable from `A` to `B`. I try to have another delegate from `B` to `A`, so that I can control `A` from `B`. I tried to created another delegate, but it does not work. Since I already imported A.h in B.h, I can not import B.h in A.h. What should I do to set up two ways custom delegate?

A.h

```
@protocol SoundDetectDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)update_from_sound: (SKSpriteNode*) node;
@end
@interface SoundDetect : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <SoundDetectDelegate> delegate;
+ (id)sharedInstance;
-(void)beat;
@end
```

B.h

```
@interface HelloScene : SKScene <SoundDetectDelegate>
@property(nonatomic, strong) SoundDetect* sd;
@property(nonatomic, strong)Song* song;
@end
```

This is one way delegate.

I tried to have something like in B.h:

```
@protocol SceneDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)cancel_thread;
@end
@interface HelloScene : SKScene <SoundDetectDelegate>
@property(nonatomic, strong) SoundDetect* sd;
@property(nonatomic, strong)Song* song;
@end
```

but I could not have `@interface SoundDetect : NSObject <SceneDelegate>` in A.h.

The main purpose for passing variable from `B` to `A` is that I want to send a variable to `A`, so that `A` can cancel its current thread.

Thanks

Comment: what type of control you want or what specific you want to do from B to A?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using delegates ,what you have to do is, use a block with a return type of BOOL to notify whether it should be canceled or not.

Answer (score 0):

1-For passing data from A to B you can use Segue and when its delegate is called then you can pass data from A to B like this

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueFromFirstToSecond"])
   {
    UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    SecondViewController *controller = (SecondViewController *)navController.topViewController;
    controller.myValue = YES;  /// myvalue is property in secondViewCOntroller
   }
 }
```

2-For passing data from B to A you can follow these links

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/12/ios-passing-data-between-view-controllers.html

http://tomsbigbox.com/pass-data-from-modal-view-back-to-parent-in-the-ios-sdk/

Answer (score 0):

Solution - Don't import in .h do the import in .m for the reference in .h introduce forward declaration @class/@protocol

in .m - have category to di following.
@interface SoundDetect() 
@end

A.h

```
@protocol SoundDetectDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)update_from_sound: (SKSpriteNode*) node;
@end
@interface SoundDetect : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <SoundDetectDelegate> delegate;
+ (id)sharedInstance;
-(void)beat;
@end
```

B.h

```
@class SoundDetect;
@interface HelloScene : SKScene 
@property(nonatomic, strong) SoundDetect* sd;
@property(nonatomic, strong)Song* song;
@end
```

B.m

```
#import "SoundDetect.h"
@interface HelloScene()<SoundDetectDelegate>
@end

@implementation HelloScene

-(void)update_from_sound: (id) node
{

}
@end
```